# Deleting user based on their id in bridge table in php, sql are not working?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I'm creating a function where the teacher can delete their mentee when their mentee is assigned to a different teacher.

`teacher table`

```
+------+------+
| ID   | name |
+------+------+
|  101 | lili |
|  201 | mey  |
+------+------+
```

`student`

```
+------+------+
|id_s  | name |
+------+------+
|  s01 | aby  |
|  s02 | miri |
|  203 | ash  |
+------+------+
```

mentee

```
+------+--------+------+--+
| id   |id_stud |  id_tch |
+------+--------+----------
|  1   | s01    |   101   |
|  2   | s02    |   101   | 
|  3   | s02    |   201   |
+------+--------+---------+
```

I want to delete the student id in the bridge table where the id is `s01` and the teacher id is `101`. I don't want to delete the whole student information. Because the student is still available, it just that the student is assigned to a different teacher. That's why I'm creating the delete function.

This is my display table

```
<tr class="del_mentee<?php echo $fetch['id']?>">
    <td><center><?php echo "$i";$i++?></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $fetch['id']?></center></td>
    <td><?php echo $fetch['name']?></td>    
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-delete" id="<?php echo $fetch['id']?>" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></center></td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-delete').on('click', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#modal_confirm").modal('show');
        $('#btn_yes').attr('name', id);
    });
    $('#btn_yes').on('click', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('name');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete_mentee.php",
            data:{
                id: id
            },
            success: function(){
                $("#modal_confirm").modal('hide');
                $(".del_mentee" + id).empty();
                $(".del_mentee" + id).html("<td colspan='6'><center class='text-danger'>Deleting...</center></td>");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".del_mentee" + id).fadeOut('slow');
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

`delete_mentee.php`

```
<?php
    require_once 'db.php';
    
    if(ISSET($_POST['id'])){
        mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM `mentee` WHERE `mentee.id` = '$_POST[id]'"));
    }
?>
```

I don't get any error it, but somehow the delete function is not working, is my delete query right? Because the SQL is not working and I'm not sure why it did not work.

I want to achieve a result that I can delete the particular mentee that I don't work with anymore.

Comment: Is your _bridge_ table called _mentee_ or _bridge_?

Comment: the bridge table is called `mentee`

Comment: Please change your code like ```mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM `mentee` WHERE `mentee`.`id` = '".$_POST['id']."'");```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete whole record from the bridge then you can use delete statement.

```
delete from bridge where id_stud  = 's01' and id_tch = '101';
```

then the output will be like this

```
+------+--------+------+--+
| id   |id_stud |  id_tch |
+------+--------+----------
|  2   | s02    |   101   | 
|  3   | s02    |   201   |
+------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Will this remove the remove the relationship between the teacher and the student? May I know why do you suggest update?

Comment: according to this statement "I want to delete the student id in the bridge table where the id is s01 and the teacher id is 101. I don't want to delete the whole student information." i believe you want output like this ? yes since bridge is the table where you connect teacher and student, relationship is removed.

Comment: Using first approach, the relation is damaged, not removed. After some time it will cause lot of invalid rows. Instead, I'd suggest the second solution, where rows are deleted for real.

Comment: oh I actually meant that I want to delete the row inside the bridge table but I still want to make sure that the student data is available at the student table. I wanted to delete the the entire row of id`1` inside the bridge table. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: @kokobty oh i understand then second solution will work.

Comment: @biesior because we are mapping say null to teacher ? i dont think it would damage can you explain a little, i just want to know how it damages.

Comment: It just creates a wild bunch of useless data in the MM table. These data cannot be reused anymore, cause we don't know what was cleared value. IMHO it would be better to add a `deleted` flag, so OP could just mark it as non-existing relation, but in the future, he could revert it. Of course, maybe it's not required here, so raw deleting the row should be enough.

Answer (score -1):

In your case it should be:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM `mentee` WHERE `mentee`.`id` = '$_POST[id]'"));
```

or without backsticks:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM mentee WHERE mentee.id = '$_POST[id]'"));
```

Note, that when you're using

```
WHERE `mentee.id` = 123
```

it searches for `mentee.id` column in `mentee` table, instead of `id`, which you want de facto.

In this case you can remove table prefix from the query:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM mentee WHERE id = '$_POST[id]'"));
```

Another thing is security as Dharman mentioned in a comment. You should avoid passing data directly from `$_POST`, the easiest solution would be:

```
$relationId = intval($_POST['id']);
mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM mentee WHERE id = $relationId"));
```

Free thoughts:

Also, try to keep some consequence, i.e. use always autoincrement integer column for your `id`, keep column names lower-case. Just to keep convention, names of tables I'd suggest are `students`, `teachers` and `student_teacher_mm` instead of `mentee`.